# Как меняется cмысл?

Tags: пунктуация

Здравствуйте.

1.Виктор значит победитель.

2.Виктор - значит победитель.

Первый вариант корректен для описания  имени?
Второй вариант подходит для описания человека?

Или смысловой разницы нет? И можно трактовать хоть как?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(1) Значить, обозначать, означать - иметь смысл,  (2)ЗНАЧИТ - связка ЭТО, ЭТО ЕСТЬ, или вводное слово, или союз ПОЭТОМУ.

Имя происходит от латинского слова "Виктор", означающего "победитель" .
Возможны варианты: (1)Виктор - значит (=следовательно), победитель. (2)Виктор - значит (=это) победитель. С помощью этих двух форм  можно описывать  имя или рассуждать о характере человека.
Вариант "Виктор значит (=обозначает) победитель" - грамматика этого предложения оставляет желать лучшего.  Имя Виктор происходит от латинского слова, означающего "победитель". (Глагол "значить" обычно употребляется в выражениях мало/много значит, во что значит)